# Can a sudoko have more than one solution

Tags: sudoku

I was developing a sudoku game . I am just wondering if a Sudoku can have more than 1 solution or A sudoku can have just 1 unique solution.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Sudoku and not programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it generally depends on the difficulty. Easy and Medium will almost always be solvable by finding a square/s with only one possibility which will then make other squares have only one possibility and so on. Harder ones might not constrict your options so much and force you to guess and check.

Comment: This doesn't actually specify whether or not only one solution exists or not. Just because you have to "guess and check" (i.e. perform a branching search) doesn't mean that all the branches will work out in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Puzzles that have more than one solution are incomplete puzzles. Published puzzles have or are belived to have one solution. A software method selected to count solutions may miss some solutions.

Comment: A software method written correctly won't miss any solutions.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg but if all software were written correctly the world would be a very different place